# Lebesgue measure of rotation

Tags: measure-theory

I studied Linear Algebra a long time ago, so the following is confusing me a bit.

$\lambda^n$ is invariant under motions: $\lambda^n (R^{-1}(B)) = \lambda^n (B)$, where $B$ is a Borel set, and $R$ is a motion.

The problem I'm working on right now is one where I need to show that the measure of a set $B$ is the same as the measure of a set $\tilde{B}$, which is just $B$ rotated 180 degrees around the origin.

My question is, how do I express that rotation in terms of this thing called $R$?

Answer (score 1):

A 180 degree rotation about the origin is $R(x, y) = (-x, -y)$. Of course, I am assuming you are working in $\Bbb R^2$, because otherwise you need more than one angle to specify the rotation.